# How can I tell if SP1 is installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard?

Tags: operating-system, version, windows-server-2008-r2, servicepacks

I've been given access to a server and told SP1 was installed on it, but I think maybe it wasn't.
How can I check if Service Pack 1 is installed on Windows Server 2008 R2?

**What I've tried:**

If I right click Computer, then click Properties, it says "Windows Server 2008 R2" under Windows Edition. I would expect it to say "Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1" if it was installed, but I did find something in a Windows 7 forum about the Service Pack not showing up in computer properties.

If I click Control Panel - > Programs - > View Installed Updates, it's not there either. I don't see the words "Service Pack" or any reference to KB 976932, which I believe is the KB for Service Pack 1 for Server 2008 R2 as well as Windows 7. (Maybe I'm wrong?)

If I run msinfo32, it shows Version as 6.1.7600 Build 7600

If I call ver.exe from command prompt it says Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]

Is there any other way to verify if SP1 is installed? Or, could I prove it is NOT installed?

**UPDATE:** Maybe someone can move this to Server Fault?

Here's the explanation I received: "The Windows Server 2008 R2 w/sp1 is from our Microsoft download, and the key used only works on that download" Is this normal/expected behavior for a MSDN download?

Comment: I've answered this below to help you out, but this really belongs on ServerFault as it is not programming related.

Comment: @CIGuy Are you able to suggest it be moved?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Go to start > run and type winver. Hit enter and a dialog will appear. On the second line in the main dialog body, you will either see something like this:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]

Or, if SP1 is installed you will see this:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600: Service Pack 1]

If a service pack is properly installed, it will always appear in the winver dialog, so it's absence is proof that it is not installed, or is corrupted in some way.

Comment: "or is corrupted in some way." Good point.

Comment: I have a comp, I guess not sp1. I load up the command prompt from the "repair this computer" option, there is no winver option but it displays the version at the top. IT looks like the example you used for when sp1 is not installed. So, worth noting.. the version is shown at the top of the command prompt on the installation disc setup. i'm guessing winver isn't on win7sp1 installation disc either. Not surprising it doesn't work in the cmd prompt at recovery time, as winver.exe is a GUI thing in windows 7